# make divs with image and text inline

Tags: html, css

I need some help. I have been searching everywhere and I have not found anything that works. This is why I'm asking this question. I am trying to make so that a div with text and an image is inline with another div, like this:

[image]

The image and text under are all in one div. How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the divs a `display: inline-block` or `float: left` style. My preference would be `display: inline-block` as you wouldn't need to clear the float after.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to go with, `display: inline-block`. Fast answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You could try this, where the black box is the outer `<div>` and the inner two boxes are nested `<div>`s with the following CSS properties:

```
.nesteddiv{
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.nesteddiv img{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the `<figure>` and `<figcaption>` tags in combination with `display: inline-block` for this purpose:

```css
#container figure {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <figure>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/business/1" />
        <figcaption>Owner</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/business/2" />
        <figcaption>Admin</figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```